# jQuery deferred object called twice

Tags: jquery, jquery-deferred

I got the following problem with the Deferred object in jQuery 1.7. This is simplify version of my problem. Following fiddle -

http://jsfiddle.net/daljit/3gbrD/1/embedded/result/

Following is the code snippet.

```
var resolveDeferred = false;
var objDeferred = $.Deferred();

function changeDeferred() {
    objDeferred.done(myDoneMethod);
    if (resolveDeferred) {
        objDeferred.resolve();
    }
    resolveDeferred = true;
}

function myDoneMethod() {
    console.log("I am called");
}
```

```js
<input type="button" value="clickMe" onclick ="changeDeferred()" />
```

As we can see clicking twice on the 'clickme' button, show two alerts.

Is there is any way to solve the problem, so when deferred object is resolved, it only called it once as method name is same.

Sorry may be I did not explain the problem properly, the code is there just to demonstrate the problem. Because method name is same so it should not call it twice, or the way to ask the question is -
is there any method to check queue for the deferred object, so i can see how many methods are attached to deferred object and if method is already attached, so do not attached it again. 
Sorry for not being clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could fit your needs, using your own queue to check for any duplicated callback:

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/3gbrD/6/)

```
var objDeferred = $.extend({}, $.Deferred(), {
    queue: [],
    done: function () {
        var callback = arguments[0];
        if (!~$.inArray(callback.toString(), this.queue)) {  
            this.queue.push(callback.toString());
            this.then($.proxy(function(){this.queue = [];callback()},this));
        }         
        return this
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

On first click `changeDeferred` function set `resolveDeferred` to `true` and add `myDoneMethod` to `objDeferred`.
On second click you add again `myDoneMethod` to `objDeferred` and resolve it.
All `done` calling after resolving, you add two callbacks - two calls.

Comment: thanks for comments, I understand the code, the code is there just to demonstrate the problem. Because method name is same so it should not call it twice, or is there any method to check queue of the deferred object, so i can see if this method is already attached, so do not attached it again. Thanks,

Comment: There is [no method](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) to check done callback stack. Better to do it defore adding something to Deffered object.

Comment: You should use http://api.jquery.com/deferred.state/ in place of the resolveDeferred variable as fiddled here http://jsfiddle.net/3gbrD/5/

Answer (score 1):

Here's a version based on A Wolff's answer but with a new method, `.doneUnique()`,  leaving `.done()` available for non-unique use.

```
function myDeferred() {
    return $.extend({}, $.Deferred(), {
        dummyQueue: $.Callbacks(),
        doneUnique: function () {
            var that = this;
            $.each(arguments, function(i, fn) {
                if($.isArray(fn)) {
                    that.done(fn);//add arrays of callbacks unconditionally 
                }
                else if (!that.dummyQueue.has(fn)) {//test - already added?
                    that.done(fn);
                    that.dummyQueue.add(fn);//remember fn, so it's not added again
                }
            });
            return this;//for method chaining
        }
    });
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/3gbrD/7/)**

NOTES:

- A dummy `$.Callbacks()` queue is used for remembering unique callbacks rather than a plain array, allowing use of `.has()`, which is arguably less cumbersome than `$.inArray()`.
- Callbaks that successfully fall through the uniqueness trap end up in the standard `.done()` queue.
- `.doneUnique()` mimics `.done()` in that it will handle multiple arguments (multiple callbacks in a single call).
- Provision is made for passing arrays of callbacks. Such arrays are added unconditionally (ie no uniqueness check is made for array-wrapped callbacks). This provides the option of forcing `.doneUnique()` to behave like `.done()`.